# copy object and change date won't work

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, loops, momentjs

The last two day's I tried everything at this code to change the event date in the object. But the output is not good. It sets alle events date to 
2018-06-09. This is the code

```
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var moment = require('moment');
function insert(data) {
  var events = [];
  if (data.when.singledates.length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.when.singledates.length; i++) {
        var ret = data;
        ret['event'] = {
          "date": moment.utc(ret.when.singledates[i].date, "DD/MM/YYYY").toISOString()
        }
        events.push(ret);
        console.log(ret);
    }
      insertevents(data, events);
  }
}
function insertevents(data, events) {
  console.log(events);
}

var data = {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b33eb86d6687e7a4b94286e"),
    "when" : {
        "singledates" : [
            {
                "endtime" : "21:30:00",
                "date" : "02/06/2018",
                "status" : null,
                "starttime" : "19:00:00",
                "extrainformation" : null
            },
            {
                "endtime" : "21:30:00",
                "date" : "07/06/2018",
                "status" : null,
                "starttime" : "19:00:00",
                "extrainformation" : null
            },
            {
                "endtime" : "21:30:00",
                "date" : "09/06/2018",
                "status" : null,
                "starttime" : "19:00:00",
                "extrainformation" : null
            },
        ],
        "datepatterns" : []
    }
}
insert(data);
```

The output of the console.log(ret) is like this:

```
{ _id: 5b33eb86d6687e7a4b94286e,
  when: 
   { singledates: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
     datepatterns: [] },
  event: { date: '2018-06-02T00:00:00.000Z' } }
{ _id: 5b33eb86d6687e7a4b94286e,
  when: 
   { singledates: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
     datepatterns: [] },
  event: { date: '2018-06-07T00:00:00.000Z' } }
{ _id: 5b33eb86d6687e7a4b94286e,
  when: 
   { singledates: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
     datepatterns: [] },
  event: { date: '2018-06-09T00:00:00.000Z' } }
```

So you can see the event date is all set nice. But when i print out the console.log(events); the dates are not set good. It all shows the same date

```
[ { _id: 5b33eb86d6687e7a4b94286e,
    when: { singledates: [Array], datepatterns: [] },
    event: { date: '2018-06-09T00:00:00.000Z' } },
  { _id: 5b33eb86d6687e7a4b94286e,
    when: { singledates: [Array], datepatterns: [] },
    event: { date: '2018-06-09T00:00:00.000Z' } },
  { _id: 5b33eb86d6687e7a4b94286e,
    when: { singledates: [Array], datepatterns: [] },
    event: { date: '2018-06-09T00:00:00.000Z' } } ]
```

Can somebody please help me out.

Comment: Push the item to particular index in the array

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.when.singledates.length; i++) {
  var ret = data;
  // mutate ret
  // push ret to array
```

`data` is the big single data object - it's not a primitive, it's an object, so you might view it as a reference to a memory location rather than something whose value gets copied when you assign it to another variable. When you mutate `ret`, you mutate the original object - you don't have a *copy* on each iteration, so the final array is made up of 3 elements, all referencing the same object (`data`), which has been mutated multiple times (and whose last mutation assigned the `date` property to `2018-06-09T00:00:00.000Z`)

If you want to push *separate* objects to your `events` array, deep clone `data` on every iteration before pushing. Quick way would be to serialize and deserialize, which will work since the nested values in `data` are all ultimately primitives:

```
var ret = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
```